# In a column, find all cells with same text inside. Then sum all the values in the same rows but different column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, vlookup

Imagine the scenario in the image:

[image]

My database is composed by 980 names for 9,800 rows so I really hope I can find an easy formula for it. I know I will have to use VLOOKUP but I don't know how to sum the rows after I find them.

Starting from the list of names (`alex`, `mark`, `steven`) how can I get the total for each name?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a macro for this, but it's so easy to do it without one that it wouldn't be worth the effort unless this is a frequent task.

1. Copy the names column to a new sheet
2. Remove duplicates
3. Use [SUMIF](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/sumif.php) to get the total for each unique name

Comment: Looks like the OP has a list of the unique names already - this answer could be improved by explaining how to use SUMIF / SUMIFS here in greater detail - particularly using '*' as a wildcard.